# Error in DataStax Cassandra system.log - ERROR [PO-thread-15] HistogramInfoPlugin.java:272 - Error performing periodic update of histogram table

Tags: cassandra, datastax

It's Datstax 5.03/Cassandra 3.09. The cluster has been running for a while without error until now.  The error appears every 10 seconds even the cluster is idle. It looks like it's related to DSE Histogram tables. I googled but found nothing to fix it.

---

```
ERROR [PO-thread-15] 2017-04-28 09:33:55,651  HistogramInfoPlugin.java:272 - Error performing periodic update of histogram table
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Unable to keep up. Some tasks were not executed.
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.ThreadPoolPlugin.lambda$onActivate$35(ThreadPoolPlugin.java:127) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.ThreadPoolPlugin.submit(ThreadPoolPlugin.java:287) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.ThreadPoolPlugin.submit(ThreadPoolPlugin.java:275) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.reporting.snapshots.histograms.HistogramInfoPlugin$PeriodicUpdateTask.runSubtask(HistogramInfoPlugin.java:285) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.reporting.snapshots.histograms.HistogramInfoPlugin$PeriodicUpdateTask.lambda$null$31(HistogramInfoPlugin.java:251) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at com.datastax.bdp.reporting.snapshots.histograms.HistogramInfoPlugin$PeriodicUpdateTask.lambda$null$32(HistogramInfoPlugin.java:251) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4707) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1080) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at com.datastax.bdp.reporting.snapshots.histograms.HistogramInfoPlugin$PeriodicUpdateTask.lambda$run$33(HistogramInfoPlugin.java:249) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at com.datastax.bdp.reporting.snapshots.histograms.HistogramInfoPlugin$PeriodicUpdateTask.run(HistogramInfoPlugin.java:226) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```